# Is there a difference?

Tags: javascript

Take the following code example

block 1

```
var myObj = {}

if(true){
 myObj = {
   name: "John",
   age: 54,
   phone: "33333"
 }
}else {
  myObj = {
   code: "E233",
   qty: "34"
 }
}
```

block 2

```
if(true){
 var myObj = {
   name: "John",
   age: 54,
   phone: "33333"
 }
}else {
  var myObj = {
   code: "E233",
   qty: "34"
 }
}
```

Is there a drawback in declaring variable **myObj** inside **if/else** statement?

Answer (score 0):

Because 'var' is hoisted there isn't so much a difference technically, however one risk that could pop up is if you're refactoring and change the name of one variable.

If you only change one declaration, you may not see the expected behavior from your script as the unchanged declaration/assignment will be valid but unused.

Whereas if you declare the variable once and forget to rename one of the assignments, it will throw an error since the old variable name is no longer declared in the scope, which makes it much easier to catch and fix such mistakes.